# jQuery method called by a string?

Tags: jquery

i saw this code on navigation bar , first time i saw this type

```
var logoSH = fixIT ? 'show' : 'hide';
$('#mini-logo')
```

Ignore the

> fixIT

It contains `true` or `false`

There is no`.` after `$('#mini-logo')` and first time I am seeing the `hide()` and `show()` method being called this way by hide.

How does it work?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565681/javascript-square-bracket-function-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript these are equivalent:

```
myObj.SomeProperty

myObj["SomeProperty"]
```

So this:

```
$("someSelector").hide();
```

is equivalent to:

```
$("someSelector")["hide"]();
```

The code you posted is equivalent to:

```
if (fixIT) {
     $('#mini-logo').show(300);
}
else {
     $('#mini-logo').hide(300);
}
```

But it's a little more compact and (IMHO) a lot less readable. Although, to be fair, it does ensure that the argument passed to `.show` or `.hide` (e.g. `300`) is always the same which might be important to you. Also, if you had more than one argument to pass (and they were the same in both cases) it might be a little more useful too.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has two [member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators): [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) and [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). Both these are used to access the members of an object.

The dot notation is used when you have a fixed property key to access, where as the square bracket notation is used when you have a key which is a key

When you say `$('#mini-logo')[logoSH](300)`, assuming `logoSH == 'show'` it is equivalent to `$('#mini-logo').show(300)`